# : was unexpected at this time. Batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
TITLE The Fighters
color 04
menu
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo  ###  ######   #####  #   #  #######  #####   ######
echo  #      #      #      #   #     #     #       #     #
echo  ###    #      # ###  #####     #     #####   #######    
echo  #      #      #   #  #   #     #     #       #   #
echo  #      #      #   #  #   #     #     #       #    #
echo  #    ######   #####  #   #     #     #####   #     #
echo.
echo     Developed By:
echo.           
echo.
echo        1). Start Game
echo        2). Help
echo        3). Exit
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                    Alpha 2.0
set /p number=

if %number%== 1 goto fight
if %number%== 2 goto help
if %number%== 3 exit

:fight
cls
echo Welcome to the Fighting Arena.
echo Press 1,2, or 3 to fight an enemy.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo   _____________________
echo  |                     |-
echo -|                     |
echo  |                     |-
echo -|                     |
echo  |                     |-
echo -|                     |-
echo  |                     |
echo -|                     |-
echo  |                     |
echo -|                     |-
echo  |                     |
echo -|                     |-
echo  |_____________________|
```

I don't know why... but when I click 1 it says : was unexpected at this time.
If someone could answer this I'd extremely appreciate it.
Also...
Please don't steal my code ;-;

This is a small game im making. Using Notepad. Its fairly easy.

Answer (score 0):

| is special character  (for output redirection or for for conditional execution when it's double) in batch file.Change all `|` with `^|` .

Consider also using of `MODE` command:

```
@echo off
TITLE The Fighters
color 04
rem ----
mode con cols=80 lines=50
rem ----
menu
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo  ###  ######   #####  #   #  #######  #####   ######
echo  #      #      #      #   #     #     #       #     #
echo  ###    #      # ###  #####     #     #####   #######    
echo  #      #      #   #  #   #     #     #       #   #
echo  #      #      #   #  #   #     #     #       #    #
echo  #    ######   #####  #   #     #     #####   #     #
echo.
echo     Developed By: RyeGuyXD
echo.           
echo.
echo        1). Start Game
echo        2). Help
echo        3). Exit
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                    Alpha 2.0
set /p number=

if %number%== 1 goto fight
if %number%== 2 goto help
if %number%== 3 exit

:fight
cls
echo Welcome to the Fighting Arena.
echo Press 1,2, or 3 to fight an enemy.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo   _____________________
echo  ^|                     ^|-
echo -^|                     ^|
echo  ^|                     ^|-
echo -^|                     ^|
echo  ^|                     ^|-
echo -^|                     ^|-
echo  ^|                     ^|
echo -^|                     ^|-
echo  ^|                     ^|
echo -^|                     ^|-
echo  ^|                     ^|
echo -^|                     ^|-
echo  ^|_____________________^|
pause >nul
goto :fight
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make it more robust:

```
:menu
cls

echo                    Alpha 2.0
set "number="
set /p "number=Enter 1,2 or 3 : "

if "%number%"=="1" goto fight
if "%number%"=="2" goto help
if "%number%"=="3" exit
goto :menu

:fight
```